# What is Pre-online and Post-online triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

what is pre-online and post-online triggers?i am not really sure.
i am using for failover management of DB2 9.7 and i need to used pre-online and post-online scripts. Any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that those terms refer to part of DB2's support for Microsoft Failover Clustering Support.  [From the Publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0007402.html) (there is more information on that page):

> **Pre-online and post-online scripts**
>
> You can run scripts both before and
>   after a DB2 resource is brought online. These scripts are referred to
>   as pre-online and post-online scripts respectively. Pre-online and
>   post-online scripts are .BAT files that can run DB2 and system
>   commands.
>
> In a situation when multiple instances of DB2 might be running on the
>   same machine, you can use the pre-online and post-online scripts to
>   adjust the configuration so that both instances can be started
>   successfully. In the event of a failover, you can use the post-online
>   script to perform manual database recovery. Post-online script can
>   also be used to start any applications or services that depend on DB2.

[Here is a whitepaper on implementing such scripts](http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/dm/db2/0301nomani/0301nomani.pdf), but it's a little older (created for UDB v8.1, which is well out of support), but maybe it will give you something to start from.  The scripts are described starting on page 34.

Comment: Firstly thanks for replying and thanks a lot for the help.I have one more qn: Are these script neccessary for the Failover management or is there any other way of doing Failover?

Comment: If you're on Windows, I'm not sure if there's another method of automated failover.  For Linux/UNIX, you can have failover with Heartbeat ( ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/pubs/papers/hadr_ha.pdf ) or using db2haicu ( http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/data/dm-0909hasharedstorage/DB2v97HASharedStorage.pdf ), and also Tivoli System Automation, if you're willing to shell out some money ( http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/e0f384d0-b8bf-2b10-3f9b-d7f7b70d06a2?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true whitepaper from SAP)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which method would u suggest?

Comment: To be honest, I've never had to implement something like this myself.  Sorry.  :-(